# Do internal outgoing links affect rank of the origin page

Tags: seo, search-results, pagerank, google-ranking

I have few hundred top ranking pages (with good SEPRs) on my website. Now I would like to add links to internal pages from those top ranking pages (aimed at additional value for users). But I have a doubt if those links would dilute the page rank of the origin pages. Is my worry justified?

Answer (score 1):

Once again I find myself repeating the same words "No one knows how the Google Algo actually works" but after that being said... I don't think internal linking will affect the rankings that much. Just don't go overboard with the internal linking and try to link to pages that also have a chance to rank better. i.e. don't do internal linking to low quality pages.

Comment: Hi, I understand that the Algo is too very complicated. However, I was expecting some deeper guidance may be based on how ranking algorithms are patented.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion and experience, internal linking may be google ranking factor.
So, too many internal linking to low quality pages from top ranking pages somewhat may harm google ranking. The number of links may be different upon the scale of sites.
How many pages does your site have?